# Area of a billiard and its preservation

Tags: geometry, analysis, billiards

From S. Tabachnikov's *Geometry and billiards*

> Consider a plane billiard table $D$ whose boundary is
>   a smooth closed curve $γ$. Let $M$ be the space of unit tangent vectors
>   $(x, v)$ whose foot points $x$ are on $γ$ and which have inward directions.
>   A vector $(x, v)$ is an initial position of the billiard ball. The ball moves
>   freely and hits $γ$ at point $x_1$; let $v_1$ be the velocity vector reﬂected
>   oﬀ the boundary. The billiard ball map $T\colon M \to M$ takes $(x, v)$ to
>   $(x_1 , v_1)$. [...]
>
> Parameterize $γ$ by arc length $t$ and let $α$ be the angle between
>   $v$ and the positive tangent line of $γ$. Then $(t, α)$ are coordinates on
>   $M$; in particular, $M$ is the cylinder. A fundamental property of the
>   billiard ball map is the existence of an invariant area form.
>
> **Theorem 3.1.** The area form $ω = \sin α \,dα \wedge dt$ is $T$-invariant.

This seems really important as it let us apply Poincaré's recurrence theorem, but I don't understand what this *area* is that is being preserved.

My question would probably be *What is an area form?*. I've found some definitions online, but they are just too advanced for me. Is it possible to rephrase the theorem above in simpler terms or should I wait until I get necessary tools to understand that?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma(s)$ for $s \in [0, L]$ be the archlength parametrized boundary of the domain $D$. For each point $\gamma(s)$ on $\gamma$ consider the unit (tangent) circle centered at $\gamma(s)$ parametrized by angle $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi]$ measured from $\dot{\gamma}(s)$ in a counterclockwise direction. Hence, you get the set of points $(s,\alpha) \in [0,L] \times [0,2\pi]$ and because $0$ and $L$ are identified and $0$ and $2\pi$ are also identified, you can think that (by abusing some notation) $(s,\alpha) \in S^1 \times S^1$ where $S^1$ is the unit circle, which we can think of as $S^1 \cong \gamma \cong \Big( [0,L]\mod L \Big) \cong \Big([0,2\pi] \mod 2\pi\Big)$.

The discrete time evolution of the billiard is realized as follows: we start from a point $(x, v)$ where $x \in \gamma$ and $v$, which we can think of as a point on $S^1$ centered at $x$, is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ pointing from point $x$ in a direction of the billiard trajectory inside the domain $D$. During the motion of the point inside $D$, the trajectory is a striaght line and the velocity is always $v$ (so uniform motion) until the point reaches again the boundary $\gamma$ of $D$ at a point $x_1 \in \gamma$ and after reflection in $\gamma$ we obtain a new direction vector $v_1$. Thus we have a map $$\Phi : \gamma \times S^1 \to \gamma \times S^1$$ $$(x,v) \mapsto (x_1,v_1)$$
Since $(s,\alpha)$ are natural coordinates on the space (it is a torus) $\gamma \times S^1 \cong S^1 \times S^1$, we can represent the point $x$ as the coordinate $s$ and the direction vector $v$ by its angle $\alpha$ with the tangent $\dot{\gamma}(s)$. Hence 
$$\Phi : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$$ $$(s,\alpha) \mapsto (s_1,\alpha_1)$$ is a map defined on a subset of the torus mapping it into the torus.

However, the vector $v$ can only point inside the domain $D$, so the angle $\alpha$ can change only between $0$ and $\pi$ (only the directions pointing on one side of the tangent $\dot{\gamma}(s)$). So technically, the map $\Phi$ is defined as follows

$$\Phi : S^1 \times (0,\pi) \to S^1 \times (0,\pi)$$ $$(s,\alpha) \mapsto (s_1,\alpha_1)$$

where $ S^1 \times (0,\pi)$ is a cylinder. The form $\omega = \sin(\alpha)\, d\alpha \wedge ds$ is a symplectic form on $ S^1 \times (0,\pi)$ and the map $\Phi$ preserves it (it is a symplectic map), i.e. $\Phi^*\omega = \omega$. Thus

$ S^1 \times (0,\pi), \, \omega$ is a two dimensional symplectic manifold. But in dimension two, $\omega$ is also an area form. Therefore, $\Phi$ preserves area. And here is where the Poincare recurrence theorem applies.

Area form is a form that allows you to introduce the notion of area on a manifold, in our case, the surface $ S^1 \times (0,\pi)$. If $K \, \subset \, S^1 \times (0,\pi)$ is a measurable subset, then

$$\text{Area}(K) = \int_{K} \omega = \int \int_{K} \sin(\alpha)\, d\alpha \,ds$$ You may have different notions of ares on the same space.